# How to pass keyboard hotkeys from VMWare Windows VM back to OSX host?

Tags: macos, keyboard, automator, vmware, virtualization

I'm running VMWare 5 on a MacBook Pro, and I'd like to be able to send certain combinations of keys out to OSX while working in my Windows VM.  I've set up a couple Automator scripts that do Play/Pause/Next on my Google Music tab in Chrome when I hit Ctrl-Cmd-Z, Ctrl-Cmd-X, and so on.  They work great while I'm using any other OSX app, but VMWare traps the keys and routes them to Windows, so that they no longer function as global hotkeys.

Is there a way to fix this?  I see options to map certain keys on the Mac keyboard to others in Windows, but no way to do the reverse.

Answer (score -1):

That's easy.

Disable the Auto Capture Keyboard.